# How to create a a Maybe equivalent for vectors of vectors?

Tags: haskell, vector, algebraic-data-types

I am trying to get this to work:

```
type CharVector = V.Vector Char
type CharMatrix = V.Vector CharVector

data MaybeCharMatrix =
  Nothing
  | CharMatrix
```

But I am unable to do the following things:

1) Pattern matching

```
test :: MaybeCharMatrix -> Int
test Nothing = -1 -- Doesn't matter, is just to illustrate
test <something> = ? -- Somehow be able to do: cols <something> * rows
```

2) Deriving show instance:

```
instance Show MaybeCharMatrix where
  show Nothing = ""
  show <something> = "Cols: " ++ cols <something> ++ ", Rows: " ++ rows <something>
```

How can this be achieved? Are there other efficient ways to do it?

Comment: `data MaybeCharMatrix = Nothing | CharMatrix` - here CharMatrix is a constructor AFAIK, **not** the type that's also called `CharMatrix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using:

```
type MaybeCharMatrix = Maybe CharMatrix

test :: MaybeCharMatrix -> Int
test Nothing = -1
test (Just matrix) = ...
```

This doesn't allow you to create your own custom Show instance, so here's another option:

```
newtype MaybeCharMatrix = MCM (Maybe CharMatrix)

test :: MaybeCharMatrix -> Int
test (MCM Nothing) = -1
test (MCM (Just matrix)) = ...some function of matrix...

instance Show (MaybeCharMatrix) where
    show (MCM Nothing) = "the nothing string"
    show (MCM (Just matrix)) = ... "Cols: " ++ show (cols matrix) ++ ...
```

I think you're better off just using the `type` alias (first option). Then you can use all of the functions which operate on Maybe values directly.

`show` is best used for a Haskell representation of the value - i.e. it should be a valid Haskell expression. If you want a custom rendering of the value, just use a different name for the rendering function - e.g. `dumpMatrix`.

**Update**

based on your comment you need something like:

```
data MaybeCharMatrix = MyNothing | MyJust CharMatrix

test :: MaybeCharMatrx -> Int
test MyNothing = -1
test (MyJust matrix) = ... can use matrix here ...

instance Show MaybeCharMatrix where
  show MyNothing = "my nothing"
  show (MyJust matrix) = "... Cols: " ++ show (cols matrix) ++ ...
```

Comment: It's my fault. The question is a simplified case of what I want. It was just an example of the concept. I would like to be able is to implement the concept behind the question (for learning purposes). Sorry if it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with the data type declaration. In general, type declarations are of the form.

```
data <type> <args> = <constructor 1> <args>
                   | <constructor 2> <args>
                   | ...
                   | <constructor n> <args>
```

In otherwords, the first expression in each clause of the data declaration is taken to be the data constructor. So, when you used your data type.

```
data MaybeCharMatrix = Nothing | CharMatrix
```

Haskell treats `CharMatrix` as a data constructor not a type. Your definition of `Nothing` also conflicts with the standard library defintion, so you should change its name. What you really want is something like this.

```
data MaybeCharMatrix = NothingCM | JustCM CharMatrix
```

That creates a data constructor `JustCM` which takes a `CharMatrix` as its argument. Then, you can pattern match like this.

```
test :: MaybeCharMatrix -> Int
test NothingCM = -1
test (JustCM mat) = <code>

instance Show MaybeCharMatrix where
    show NothingCM = ""
    show (JustCM mat) = "Cols: " ++ cols mat ++ ", Rows: " ++ rows mat
```

Comment: Would also accept your answer but the other guy answered first. Sorry.